# PHP's SimpleXMLElement analog for Node.js

Tags: javascript, xml, api, node.js

The best XML reading and writing API I've ever used is PHP's [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php). For example, to create a DOM of the following XML text:

```
<root>
    <foo>
        <bar baz="goo">
            moo
        </bar>
    </foo>
</root>
```

in PHP one would just write:

```
$root = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
$root->foo->bar = 'moo';
$root->foo->bar['baz'] = 'goo';
```

Same style for reading XML, with addition of `xpath()` function.

I heard people calling it a "builder pattern". Not quite sure if that's appropriate. Anyway, is there any API under Node.js having a comparable ease of use?

Comment: please do me one favor and stop comparing nodejs to php...

Comment: Huh? What are you talking about? Have you even read the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it has [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/).

jsdom allows you to use the DOM as if you were on the client.

You can even use jQuery with it if bare DOM scares you.

Example from doc:

```
// Run some jQuery on a html fragment
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

jsdom.env('<p><a class="the-link" href="https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom">jsdom\'s Homepage</a></p>', [
  'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'
],
function(errors, window) {
  console.log("contents of a.the-link:", window.$("a.the-link").text());
});
```