# Equivalent to PHP's simplexml_load_string in Node.js

Tags: php, xml, node.js, simplexml

In PHP I have

```
$this->response->body = simplexml_load_string($this->response->body);
```

How would I perform the same action in a Node.js project?

Comment: Are you looking for [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton The `simplexml_load_string` function does return a SimpleXMLElement

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js

Comment: @cmorrissey looking into this, it looks promising.  Could you provide an example?

Comment: This question could be improved a lot by being clearer on what you want to do with the SimpleXML-like object once you've got it. At the moment it amounts to "how do I parse XML?" which is quite a broad topic - a quick search shows up [64 npm modules matching the term "parse xml"](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=parse+xml) - so it's quite hard for people to give specific examples of equivalent functionality.

Comment: @IMSoP All I am asking is how to receive the same output that this function gives in Node, given the same input.  It is quite specific.

Comment: The "output" of that function is an interactive object with lots of PHP-specific "magic" behaviour, such as `$node->child` and `$node['attribute']`; there's never going to be a nodeJS module which has 100% identical behaviour. But the SimpleXMLElement isn't really an "output", it's a means to some end; if you can describe what task you want to achieve using the object, then people can give you examples of how to do that using one of the many nodeJS XML libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/) as @florian-margaine exemplified here [PHP's SimpleXMLElement analog for Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631297/phps-simplexmlelement-analog-for-node-js).

```
// Run some jQuery on a html fragment
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

jsdom.env('<p><a class="the-link" href="https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom">jsdom\'s Homepage</a></p>', [
  'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'
],
function(errors, window) {
  console.log("contents of a.the-link:", window.$("a.the-link").text());
});
```

EDIT:

So a research a little and you can use: **dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/xml.html that I found be more easy to use.**

Here a example: **jsfiddle.net/arthurvasconcelos/gwpqyf06/**

Comment: Can you explain how you would use it in my situation? I'm not quite sure what's output the object in this example.

Comment: @tibsar i edit my answer with another way to do what you want. hope to help.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use jsdom

A JavaScript implementation of the WHATWG DOM and HTML standards, for use with Node.js.

```
// Run some jQuery on a html fragment
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

jsdom.env('<p><a class="the-link" href="https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom">jsdom\'s Homepage</a></p>', [
  'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'
],
function(errors, window) {
  console.log("contents of a.the-link:", window.$("a.the-link").text());
});
```

Comment: Can you explain how you would use it in my situation? I'm not quite sure what's output the object in this example.